# Read the columns of a csv file and save them each column in a variable using Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to save each column of a csv file into a variable (e.g.: column called 'a' in the 'varA' variable, column called 'b' in the 'varB' variable, etc).
I have tried to do it, in this way:

```
with open(data_file_name, 'r') as csvfile:
    varA = [int(row["a"]) for row in DictReader(csvfile)] 
    varB = [float(row["b"]) for row in DictReader(csvfile)]
    lenA = len(varA)
    lenB = len(varB)
```

I have check the file by my own, and all columns has the same length, but in this code I can get the lenA with an specific value, but not the lenB (because when I printed lenB I see 0 instead of the same value as lenA). 
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas :

**file.csv**:

```
a,b,c
1,0,1
1,0,0
0,0,1
1,0,0
```

Do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

var_a = df['a']
var_b = df['b']
var_c = df['c']
```